# Excel - How can I select a person from a range based on the day of the week?

Tags: excel

I've got a group of people who meet four days a week. Depending on which day is it, certain people are available. I'd like to assign note taking using a formula that would see who is available on a particular day of the week and select them sequentially. This probably needs VBA, but I'm not much of a programmer yet.

Below is a sample set of data with some names and the days of the week they're available. I was hoping that I could use an IF statement then I could nest several IF statements together.

> "if(weekday(cell)=1,choose from the range of names,..."

I have no idea if this can work without VBA, but I'm willing to try VBA as well though I'm not much of a programmer. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Name    Avail

Peter   M,W

Trent   M,W,F

Jennifer    M,W,F

Dixon   M,T,W,F

Heather M,W,F

Mark    M,W

Laurie  M,W,F

Charles M,T,W,F

Jake    M,T,W,F

Victor  M,W,F

v/r
Syrena

Answer (score 1):

It is best to split the data into rows labeled by names and columns labeled by days of the week with a 1 in the intersection of a row and column if the person corresponding to the row is available on the day corresponding to the column. The following might give you an idea (the formula in the bar was entered into G2 and copied down):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your `Names` data start at A2, and `Avail` data start at B2, write in a row starting at C1 the days.

Enter in C2 : `=IFERROR(SIGN(FIND(C$1;$B$2:$B$11));0)`, copy to the left.

Enter in C3 : `=IFERROR(MAX(C$2:C2)+SIGN(FIND(C$1;$B$2:$B$11));0)`, copy to the left and down.